# bash case statement quoting behaves as documented, but please explain

Tags: bash, switch-statement, glob, quoting

c.f. the [`case` example here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Patterns)
Specifically:

```
$: g=a*[b]; case $g in $g) echo 'unquoted pattern' ;; "$g") echo 'quoted pattern' ;; esac
quoted pattern
```

A simple string behaves exactly as expected -

```
$: g=a; case $g in $g) echo 'unquoted pattern' ;; "$g") echo 'quoted pattern' ;; esac
unquoted pattern
```

I made sure there was no matching file to glob, no `shopt` options muddying the water, and tested the value explicitly:

```
$: echo @$g@ "@$g@" $g "$g"
@a*[b]@ @a*[b]@ a*[b] a*[b]
$: [[ $g == "$g" ]] && echo ok || echo no
ok
```

So why *does* it, in this case, choose the second option?
Shouldn't both evaluate to the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `case` statement uses pattern matching, not string equality, to compare the word to each pattern.

The *pattern* `a*[b]` matches any string starting with an `a`, with zero or more characters followed by a single `b`. It does not match the *string* `a*[b]`, because that string ends with a `]`, not a `b`.

Comment: Bah, yeah I had regexes on the brain. Will fix.

Comment: To elaborate in retrospect - "[There are a few cases where double quotes may be safely omitted: ...The word following a case keyword...](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F)" The `case` quotes its argument, so the unquoted globbing metacharacters do not match the same characters in the quoted version of the string.